# How to manage multiple uploads/downloads in firebase storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am currently working on the project which has some sort of files uploading/downloading operation and using Firebase Storage as backend storage service.For better UX it is required to show status of upload downloads such as successfully uploaded,upload failed and uploading progress.but problem is in managing multiple files uploads/downloads.I tried to work like

```
List<UploadTask> uploadTasksList;
```

but this is not working very well to manage operations.Is there any otherway to properly manage download/uploads.
or Is there some sorf of library which I can used to manage.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the [API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) for the `Task` type exposes some convenience methods for chaining together the execution of other `Task`s:

- `continueWithTask(Continuation<TResult, Task<TContinuationResult>> continuation)`

...or even some other arbitrary logic:

- `continueWith(Continuation<TResult, TContinuationResult> continuation)`

given two `UploadTask`s, usage of the former might look something like this:

```
final UploadTask task1 = storageReference1.putBytes(bytes1);
final UploadTask task2 = storageReference2.putBytes(bytes2);

task1.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        return task2;
    }
});
```

...or, more concisely with lambda syntax:

```
final UploadTask task1 = storageReference1.putBytes(bytes1);
final UploadTask task2 = storageReference2.putBytes(bytes2);

task1.continueWithTask(task -> task2);
```

should you go down this path, it would also be worth your time to read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Continuation) on the `Continuation` type - specifically around error handling.

hope that helps!